# cannot get pagination to work even with all the examples

Tags: angularjs

i have spent 3 days trying to get this to work. i have used many examples online but i just cant seem to get it right
   CONTROLLER

```
    $scope.jobArray = Job.query();
    $scope.currentPage = 1
    $scope.numPerPage = 10
    $scope.maxSize = 5;

    $scope.numPages = function () {
        return Math.ceil($scope.jobArray.length / $scope.numPerPage);
    };

    $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
        , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

        $scope.jobArray = $scope.jobArray.slice(begin, end);

    });
```

VIEW

```
     <select class="form-control" ng-model="search.jobTitle" >
      <option value="">Select</option>
     <option ng-repeat="jTitle in jobTitleList | unique:'jobTitle' " value=" {{  
     jTitle.jobTitle }}"> {{ jTitle.jobTitle }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [THIS JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/) example? It is the most simple example of doing it in my opinion. The key is to use the built in filter 'limitTo', and writing a custom 'startFrom' filter. If you have any questions about how it works in your case, set up a fiddle and we can help you out more.

```
<option ng-repeat="jTitle in jobTitleList | startFrom:currentPage*numPerPage | limitTo:numPerPage" value="{{jTitle.jobTitle}}">
    {{jTitle.jobTitle}}
</option>
```

and

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```